# Display column names in seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this code.

```
l = df.columns.values
number_of_columns=5
number_of_rows = len(l)-1/number_of_columns
plt.figure(figsize=(number_of_columns * 2, 5*number_of_rows))
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    plt.subplot(number_of_rows + 1, number_of_columns, i+1)
    sns.set_style('whitegrid')
    sns.boxplot(data=df[l[i]], color='green', orient='v')
    plt.tight_layout()
```

This is the output.

[image]

I want the output to display the column/feature name like the following image.

[image]

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should collect the [`matplotlib.axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib-axes) object returned by [`sns.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) and [add a name to its y-axis](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel.html):

```py
   #...
   ax = sns.boxplot(data=df[l[i]], color='green', orient='v')
   ax.set_ylabel(df.columns[i])
   #...
```

Comment: This works, but passing the vector to `y=` rather than `data=` will do it for you automatically.